# How to create an alphabetically sorted array out of the column in MySQL DB and pass it to the view?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter, and basically a PHP noob.
So I have this table in my DB named 'stores'.
And I want an alphabetically sorted array with elements corresponding to the column 'title' in the table stores.

I cannot seem to think of any possible solutions, at the moment!

Any help??

I use linux/ubuntu...

PS: I read in the PHP manual that sqlsrv extension can be used only on Windows platform (http://www.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php) Is there no Linux alternative for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller:

```
$res['output']=$this->modelname->get();
$this->load->view('viewname',$res);
```

Model:

```
function get()
{
$query=$this->db->query("select * from table order by title asc");
$output=$query->result();
return $output;
}
```

View :

```
<?php
foreach($output as $obj)
{
echo $obj->blah;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ORDER BY` clause in MySQL query to sort the records:

```
SELECT *
FROM stores.table_name
ORDER BY title ASC;
```